# CSS background:none inside a div with a background?

Tags: css, background

I have div wrapper and the background is white, I also have a body background (its an image) I want to have a div inside my wrapper with no white background, basically I am looking to make that div transparent to the wrapper background.

```
<div style="background:none;">ghjhjghjghj</div>
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to make the body background appear trough a `div` that is inside another `div` that have a white background. Is this possible?

Comment: If you make your child `div` have a transparent background then it will show the color of `parent div` i.e white in this case. Are you saying that you need to show the `background-image` of the `body` in that `child div` ?  BTW `background-color: transparent` and `background:none` are default properties no need to declare them explicitly.

Comment: @venkateshwar - you're right, I changed my fiddle and I didn't need to specify transparent at all. I suspect the CSS the OP is using is affecting things. user1269625 - we need some context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparent background color works in this simple example...

http://jsfiddle.net/rD93B/1/

More HTML/CSS would help identify the problem you're having.

And updated jsfiddle with white background color on container div...

http://jsfiddle.net/rD93B/3/

Another update ....

http://jsfiddle.net/rD93B/6/

This shows the background color of the container div without showing the background image

**CSS**

```
div#outer {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(http://static4.grsites.com/archive/textures/red/red001.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}


div#inner {
  background-color: inherit;
  background-image: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 2px yellow;
  color: yellow;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He is trying to make an element that is child of a white background div shows the background of body.

Comment: @rcdmk your point being? I've updated the fiddle so the container div has a white background and an image and without me specifying any background properties on the child div it still shows the background image of the parent div. Sorry, I don't see what you're saying.

Comment: He is trying to show the body's background throught the child div that is inside a white background div. Hope I was clearer this time.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did in my jsfiddle, hence my request for more contextual HTML/CSS. I'm sure there is some "general" CSS rule taking effect here. I'd suggest firing up chrome/ie developer view to see what rule is affecting the element in question.

Comment: Apologies, I just re-read and got it this time,back to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-color property and set it to: transparent on your inner div.

```
<div style="background-color: transparent;">ghjhjghjghj</div>
```

Comment: Post your full code and I'll take a look. As a rule of thumb you'll get better more complete answers when you do so.

Comment: `background: none` implicitly sets the color to transparent.

Comment: He is trying to make an element that is child of a white background div shows the background of body.